# Backbone rendering collection in other collection element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a structure that I need to render. It has linear type:

```
{districts : [
            {
                name : "D17043"                
            },
            {
                name : "D91832"
            },
            {
                name : "D32435"
            }
        ],
buildings : [
            {
                name : "B14745",
                district: "D17043",
                address: "1st str"
            },
            {
                name : "B14746",
                district : "D91832",
                address : "1st str"
            },
            {
                name : "B14747",
                district : "D17043",
                address : "1st str"
            }            
        ]
}
```

It is simplified to look a bit better. Districts have buildings attached to them. Possibly, the structure could be nested, but I thought that it would make additional troubles, and, as this "tree" is not structured I made simple object.
The question is - how it can be properly displayed with backbone? 
Right now it looks something like this (some details are left behind the scenes):

```
App.Collections.Districts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : App.Models.District
    });
    var districtsCollection = new App.Collections.Districts(data.districts);
    var districtsView = new App.Views.Districts({collection : districtsCollection});
```

then somewhere in district collection view we create a loop that make views of a single district:

```
var districtView = new App.Views.District({model : district});
```

and inside `view` of a single district i call another collection in `render` method:

```
App.Views.District = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName : 'div',
        className : 'districtListElement',
        render : function () {                
            this.$el.html(this.model.get('name'));
            var buildingsCollection = new App.Collections.Buildings(allData.buildings);
            buildingsCollection.each(function(item){
                if (item.get('district') == this.model.get('name')) {
                    var buildingView = new App.Views.Building({model : item});
                    this.$el.append(buildingView.render().el);
                }
            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });
```

This thing works but isn't it a bit creepy? Maybe there is a proper way to do it? Especially if I have other instances to be inside buildings. 
Thank you.

Comment: probably best not to create a new collection inside of a view. structure your code so that collections are created when the data is available; a (child) collection can be an attribute of another (parent) collection. then, in the parent view, create a child view (passing it the child collection), and render the child view

Comment: Thank you, Stephen, I have separated new collection creation, but for now left linear structure.